# UITableViewCell subviews disapearing on refresh then reappearing

Tags: ios, uitableview, subview

I have a strange bug where randomly, my tableViewCell contentView's subViews all disappear leaving an empty cell. Subsequently after that on each refresh of the cell, the content reappears and then disappears! I have put some debugging statements to measure the cells contentViews subview count which flips between 9 and 0, when it is 0, I print the frames of the subviews and they do indeed have frames and do exist, but there superview is nil.

What could possibly be removing all these views from the contentView?

Comment: We need some code to resolve this.

Comment: There is a lot of code, basically I have subclassed a UItableViewCell wihich gets registered in the storyboard and dequeued as normal in cellforRowAtIndexPath.  I just noticed I have overwritten layoutSubviews on my cell and forgot to call super.layoutSubviews()   could this cause this random removal of all subviews.. its as if the cell just forgot to draw them properly or something